# SSH reverse tunnel issue

Tags: networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I have 3 computers. A, B and C.

I want to SSH from computer A to C via B.

I want to do this through key authentication method. Now, to make this work:

I create a key pair on C, send the public key on B and then use use reverse tunnel SSH on C to connect to B at port x.

```
ssh -i KEY1 -f -N -R B_ipaddress:PORT:localhost:22 B_username@B_ipaddress -o GatewayPorts=yes
```

Gets connected fine.

Then, I create a second key pair at A, send the public key on B and then use this method to connect:

```
SSH -i KEY2 -p PORT B_username@B_ipaddress
```

I get Permission denied (Public Key) error. I already added the keys in authorized_keys file. Even the permissions appear to be fine. Still no luck.

If I remove the port in SSH method when connecting from A, I am able to connect directly to B without any issues. But that doesn't help me connect to C.

Any help would help. I just started out with the Networking systems. Sorry if this sounds amateurish. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be a reverse connection? If not, the -J option would be the easiest solution.

Comment: The issue I have is that Computer C has no static IP but only dynamic IP. And the only possible way I found with my limited knowledge is reverse ssh tunnel to a port on computer B and then access from computer A on that port. If -J option can work in that case then please help me with what should the ssh method look like.

Comment: I would solve this by setting up DDNS and port forwarding for the box with a dynamic IP. Thus you avoid the hassle with the reverse connection. There are plenty of tutorials out about this very problem.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically on C since C is my friend's computer and it is at a remote location. DDNS and port forwarding would require tweaking modem settings. Reverse tunnel can be done through a script.. But not able to make it work right now..